# How to wait for a GPS fix before recording location

Tags: android, service, gps, locationlistener

I am having trouble finding an approach to wait for a GPS fix in my Android application. I am running a service to record user location and want to wait for a GPS fix before I do so. Can anyone suggest a method for approaching this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just get a locationManager and request location update for GPS. Do not call getLastKnownLocation. When you get the onLocationChanged() that is your GPS fixed.

Comment: Of course. Thank you very much! I will use this with some other strategies to ensure a fix is acquired before recording data.

Answer (score 2):

This is indeed one of the critical things.
You will have the problem, that either you could have an not accurate fix, or you are waiting for an acurate one, and the user does not get an position feedback in your app.

This much depends on your app.
You can wait until the `location.getAccuarcy()` is under 30m, or the first one that have a speed over x km/h, for application swhere you want to record movement.

To show on a map, you want to take the first you get.

There is no universal soultion for this.

Comment: I have been looking at GPSlistener. will the FIRST_FIX flag not provide a solution? heres a [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/GpsStatus.html#GPS_EVENT_FIRST_FIX)